# Как на сервере запускать tcpdump без sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, sudo, wireshark

Нужно написать script, в котором будет использована tcpdump команда, но проблема в том, что без sudo выдаёт "Permission denied" или что-то в этом роде, а если использовать sudo, то нужен пароль, тогда script перестанет отвечать после команды tcpdump. Сервер CentOS.
Как на сервере запускать tcpdump без sudo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно добавить запись файл `/etc/sudoers` c директивой `NOPASSWD` и путем к скрипту

```
myusername ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script
```

Comment: Или в скрипте писать `sudo tcpdump` и тогда в /etc/sudoers прописать `myusername ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/tcpdump`

Comment: не открывает sudoers, пишет - "Permission denied" :((

Comment: От рута надо открывать `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`

Comment: да, спасибо, сейчас всё тип-топ!!

Comment: @sinedskid если ответ решает вашу задачу, отметьте его галочкой (слева от вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

[http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/суперпользователь_в_ubuntu](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B2_ubuntu) информация о том, как выполнять команды не используя sudo.