# Как задать php-скрипт на выполнение в cron?

Tags: php, cron, vesta

В панели `VestaCP`, раздел `Cron` добавить задание вида

`sudo /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/test.php`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не работает никак.

Comment: а у вас php - исполняемые файлы? а права тогда есть соответствующие? попробуйте `php .../test.php`, т.е. явно указать чем надо этот файл запускать

Comment: не работает с `php`

Comment: а что не работает? может ошибки какие? или файла там такого нет, вы проблему точнее опишите

Comment: дааа, ошибки есть, не может подключится к БД, не знает что такое `pdo`, но почему? скрипт ведь в файле работает, сейчас попробую прописать полный путь к файлу через `/home...`

Comment: в общем ошибок больше нет, из консоли выполняется, из `cron` нет

Comment: смотрите юзера под кем работает крон

Comment: приведите код php файла

Comment: из консоли уже не выполняется

Comment: под главным выполняется, admin

Answer (score 1):

Vesta запускает команды от владельца сайта, sudo не будет работать, даже у юзера admin нет доступа к sudo. На почту должны валиться письма с ошибками крона, странно что вы не упомянули это в вопросе.

Можно юзеру дать права на выполнения этой команды от sudo

Comment: Как именно дать права юзеру?

Comment: Ответ тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458365/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-tcpdump-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-sudo/458380#458380